# Self hosted GitHub and Docker Hub integration

Tags: docker, github, webhooks, dockerhub

We are attempting to link a Docker Hub image with a self hosted GitHub repository. ?The documentation found at https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/github/ works great as long as the code base is located at https://github.com/{username}.

However, we want this functionality from our https://github.{my orgs domain here}.com/{username}/{project}.

There appears to be very little documentation on this subject; anyone every try this?